# Passing messages through Promises

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make an extension where :

- background creates a new blank tab in the browser
- then update the new tab with an url
- then open a message port to the new tab
- then pass a message to content script to retrieve  element on the new tab's page
- then content script respond to background with the  title

I'm trying to do that with Promises, because after above example, I want to make it with an array of urls, so with a for loop. So I need to do it synchronously, one url after one url.

Here's my code :

background.js

```js
function createNewTab() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var newTabId = 0;
        chrome.tabs.create({
            url: "about:newtab"
        }, function(newTab) {
            resolve(newTab);
        });        
    });        
}

function updateTab(newTab) {
    console.log("updateTab try with tab " + newTab.id);
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        chrome.tabs.update(newTab.id, {
            url: "https://forum.openstreetmap.fr/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6811&start=0"
        }, function (tab) {
            if (tab.url == "https://forum.openstreetmap.fr/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6811&start=0")
                resolve(["updated", tab])
            else
                reject(["failed", null])
        });
    });
}

function connectTab(newTab) {
    console.log("connectTab try with tab " + newTab.id);
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var port = chrome.tabs.connect(newTab.id, {
            name: "scrap"
        });
        resolve(port);
    });
}

function passMsgToTab(port) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        port.postMessage({
            type: "title"
        });
        resolve("passed");
        reject("failed");
    });
}

createNewTab()
.then(function(newTab) {
    console.log("createNewTab newTab : " + newTab.id);
    return updateTab(newTab)
})
.then(function(responseTab) {
    var response = responseTab[0];
    var newTab = responseTab[1];
    console.log("updated ? " + response + " | tab : " + newTab.id);    
    if (response == "updated")
        return connectTab(newTab)
})
.then(function (port) {
    console.log("connectTab port : " + port.name);
    return passMsgToTab(port)
})
.then(function (response) {
     console.log("message passed ? " + response);
})
```

And content_script.js :

```js
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function (port) {
    console.assert(port.name == "scrap");
    port.onMessage.addListener(function (msg) {
        console.log("recieved msg : " + msg.type); 
        if (msg.type == "title") {
            var title = $("h3.first a").text();
            port.postMessage({
                title: title
            });
        }
    });
 });
```

So the first 2 steps (createTab & updateTab) success. But message passing fails. I retrieve the response from connectTab but as I'm not putting resolve in a callback function, I think it doesn't work. I can reach port.name from then() but what can I do with this port ? And Where can I put the resolve ?
I think this is the same problem with port.message.

Comment: I think you can simplify it a bit since chrome.tabs.connect returns its result synchronously and there's no need to wrap it in a Promise. BTW it's not clear why you use port-based messaging instead of the default single-time messaging. Also, 1) consider loading the Mozilla's WebExtension polyfill, 2) consider using async/await.

Comment: I was referring to one specific use case.